# Como hago estas consultas y subconsultas en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

Ok, he estado tratando de hacer unas consultas para una tarea en la que mi profesor no nos enseñó nada, estas son las tablas que tengo:

[image: Tablas de mi base de datos]

Las consultas que tengo que hacer, son las siguientes:

- Muestre los nombres de empleado, nombre del departamento al que pertenecen, y nombre de las actividades que realiza, agrupo por actividad (Group By).
- **Utilizando subconsultas** Muestre los nombres de empleado, nombre del departamento al que perteneces, y nombre de las actividades que realiza, agrupo por actividad (group by).

Algunas de las consultas que mi equipo, bueno, casi todos mis compañeros de clases tratamos de hacer, fueron las siguientes:

```
Select empleado.nombreE, depto.nombreDepto, actividad.nombreAct 
from empleado, depto, actividad 
where actividad_empleado.idEmpleado=empleado.idEmpleado 
AND empleado.idDepto=depto.idDepto 
AND actividad_empleado.idActividad=actividad.idActividad 
Group By nombreAct
```

```
Select empleado.nombreE, depto.nombreDepto, actividad.nombreAct 
from empleado, depto actividad 
where empleado.idEmpleado = (
  select actividad_empleado.idEmpleado 
  from actividad_empleado
) 
AND empleado.idDepto =(
  Select depto.idDepto 
  from depto
) 
AND actividad.idActividad =(
  Select Actividad_empleado.idActividad 
  from actividad_empleado
) 
Group by nombreAct
```

Lo mas cercano que estuvimos a hacerlo correctamente fue esto:

[image: Consulta 1]

[image: Consulta 2]

Lo que pasaba en estas, era que se nos repetía siempre el mismo nombre de empleado y no se agrupaban por actividad. Espero que alguien nos pueda ayudar con esto.

Si no me equivoco, el resultado esperado de ambas deberia ser algo así o con el nmobre de actividad ordenado alfabeticamente:
[image: Resultados esperados]

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver un ejemplo (no una descripción) del resultado esperado.

Comment: Listo, ya puse lo que se supone que deberian ser los resultados, porque ni eso se nos dijo como sería, solo nos dio la oracion que puse arriba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sentencia group by fusiona filas iguales bajo un criterio, generalmente usado con agregación para obtener resúmenes/sumarios, estadísticas, etc. Revisa la documentación de group by.

Lo que entiendo, en base al resultado esperado, es que se pide que uses **order by** (y no group by), es decir, que hay una errata en el enunciado que te han propuesto. La confusión viene porque se te pide "agrupar" para decir "ordenar" (porque se busca que "aparezcan juntos", y nuestro idioma confunde).

Confirma que el resultado esperado es el que has dicho, porque para ese caso no necesitas group by (ni tiene sentido usarlo). Por ejemplo, para conseguir el resultado que propones con la base de datos que propones:

```sql
SELECT empleado.NombreEmpleado, departamento.nombreDepartamento, actividad.nombreActividad
FROM empleado, departamento, actividad, actividadempleado
WHERE empleado.idDepartamento = departamento.idDepartamento
AND empleado.idEmpleado = actividadempleado.idEmpleado
AND actividad.idActividad = actividadempleado.idActividad
ORDER BY nombreActividad, NombreEmpleado, nombreDepartamento;
```

ORDER BY ordenará los campos en dicho orden, de esta forma se verán "juntos" (ordenados). Primero ordenará alfabéticamente por el nombre de la actividad, luego el nombre de empleado y luego el departamento. Group by, como te decía, tiene un uso distinto. Consulta algunos ejemplos por la red, hay a patadas.

**NOTA**: realmente esta consulta se puede simplificar con [INNER JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)s, pero me limito a las formas que ya manifiestas conocer (todos con todos + filtros WHERE/AND).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya solo me resta "convertirla" a subconsulta, agradezco muchisimo tu ayuda hermano, tenia ya buen rato tratando de hacerla tambien con joins, pero tampoco obtuve un resultado bueno. Nuevamente, muchas gracias :D